position of a component in JSX curly braces in the UI tree
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function Scoreboard() {
  const [isPlayerA, setIsPlayerA] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div>
      {isPlayerA &&
        <Counter person="Taylor" />
      }
      {!isPlayerA &&
        <Counter person="Sarah" />
      }
      <button onClick={() => {
        setIsPlayerA(!isPlayerA);
      }}>
        Next player!
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

function Counter({ person }) {
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);

  let className = 'counter';
  if (hover) {
    className += ' hover';
  }

  return (
    <div
      className={className}
      onPointerEnter={() => setHover(true)}
      onPointerLeave={() => setHover(false)}
    >
      <h1>{person}'s score: {score}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setScore(score + 1)}>
        Add one
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

According to the description in React official document(https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state#option-1-rendering-a-component-in-different-positions), the two Counter components in the code above are located in different positions in the UI tree.
However, I think the two Counter components are always in the position of <div><Counter /><button /></div> no matter what the isPlayerA state value is.
How do the two Counter components exist in different positions in the UI tree?
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function Scoreboard() {
  const [isPlayerA, setIsPlayerA] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div>
      {isPlayerA ? (
        <Counter person="Taylor" />
      ) : (
        <Counter person="Sarah" />
      )}
      <button onClick={() => {
        setIsPlayerA(!isPlayerA);
      }}>
        Next player!
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

function Counter({ person }) {
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);

  let className = 'counter';
  if (hover) {
    className += ' hover';
  }

  return (
    <div
      className={className}
      onPointerEnter={() => setHover(true)}
      onPointerLeave={() => setHover(false)}
    >
      <h1>{person}'s score: {score}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setScore(score + 1)}>
        Add one
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

I expected it to work like the code above.


According to the description in React official document(https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state#option-1-rendering-a-component-in-different-positions), the two Counter components in the code above are located in different positions in the UI tree.
However, I think the two Counter components are always in the position of  no matter what the isPlayerA state value is.

I think the thing you're missing is that false is a value. When you render this:
<div>
  {isPlayerA && <Counter person="Taylor" />}
  {!isPlayerA && <Counter person="Sarah" />}
  <button
    onClick={() => {
      setIsPlayerA(!isPlayerA);
    }}
  >
    Next player!
  </button>
</div>

... the div always has 3 children. It's either <Counter>, false, <button>; or false, <Counter>, <button>. So the counter moves from being the first child to the second child.
With this:
<div>
  {isPlayerA ? <Counter person="Taylor" /> : <Counter person="Sarah" />}
  <button
    onClick={() => {
      setIsPlayerA(!isPlayerA);
    }}
  >
    Next player!
  </button>
</div>

... the div always has 2 children; a <Counter> and a <button>

Even though "false" is just a value, is it in the UI tree?

I saw this following phrase in this page(https://react.dev/learn/conditional-rendering#logical-and-operator-).
“React considers false as a ‘hole' in the JSX tree, just like null or undefined, and doesn’t render anything in its place.”
So the “hole” in the phrase exists in UI Tree, but it's just not rendered, right?

The false is a node in the virtual DOM tree. It does not cause anything to be put on the real DOM.

Thanks for clarifying...In fact, I assume it is not just false, but also null, undefined, or true is evaluated within JSX (though part of virtual DOM). Would that be correct ?
